# Set property Id to a uibModal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like to know if it is possible to set an Id property to a modal generated through $uibModal so later I can capture the correspondent element by its Id. I successfully managed to generate as many modals as I need although they are not uniquely identified with the following code:

```
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'openChat.html',
        scope: $scope,
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        controller: 'openChatModalCtrl',
        windowClass: 'chat-modal',
        size: 'sm'
    }).rendered.then(function () {
        console.log('there you go!');
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*id* property may be added by `$uibModalStack` factory provided by *ui-bootstrap*:

```
$ctrl.open = function (size, windowTopClass, id) {
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
  ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  controllerAs: '$ctrl',
  size: size,
  windowTopClass: windowTopClass,
  windowTemplateUrl: 'my-window.html',
  resolve: {
    projects: function () {
      return $ctrl.projects;
    }
  }
}).rendered.then(function () {
  $uibModalStack.getTop().value.modalDomEl.attr('id', id);
});
```

note `$uibModalStack.getTop().value.modalDomEl.attr('id', id);` line, this way *id* can be passed from the template:

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-default" 
        ng-click="$ctrl.open('lg', 'my-outer-class2', 'myID2')">Open me2!</button>
```

also please note, that you can use *windowTopClass* or *windowClass* properties of the `$uibModal.open()` function, these classes will also be added to the top modal level, so you can also use them for unique selectors.

plunker with 2 buttons applying 2 different *id*s and css classes: https://plnkr.co/edit/vMw1XtyNOED8PIDP0hWe?p=preview

Comment: @audriy , can you add aria-hidden to siblings element ?

Comment: once you have reference to the `$uibModalStack.getTop().value.modalDomEl` angular element you can traverse it and assign any attribute as needed. If still need help, please specify on which element in my Plunker you want to add `aria-hidden` and I will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add "id" attribute [Ui Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) modal popup

But you can manage using variable which initialize the $uibModal, In your case it is var modalInstance

Following is the reference which may help  For e.g.

```
//Model Popup for e.g login User
var loginUser= $uibModal.open({
  .....
   ....
});

loginUser.result.then(function () {
 //Write your on success 
}, function () {
  //Write your code when model close event
});

//Other Model Popup for register User
var registerUser= $uibModal.open({
  .....
   ....
});

registerUser.result.then(function () {
 //Write your on success 
}, function () {
  //Write your code when model close event
});
```

Hopefully I have answered your question