# How to use custom css on uibmodal? How to customize the width and height of a uibmodal for a particular selection item?

Tags: angularjs

I have various menu items which use the same uibmodal when clicked on any of them. Only for one of the menu selections, I want the uibmodal to be displayed as a smaller size. I tried the following:

```
$scope.profile = function() {
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'views/modal/user_profile.html',
                controller: 'UserController',
                scope: $scope,
                windowClass: 'userFileWindow',
                size: 'sm'
            });
        };
```

Size: sm is not helping. It shows the default size as any other menu selection, how to I modify the width and height of this uibmodal?

I am new to working to Angular, sorry if its an insane question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going one step forward, how to add the css class to this uibModal?

```
.userFileWindow {

    .modal-sm{
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
}
}
```

Comment: My bad, userFileWindow is the generic windowClass. How to create a separate ID for this menu item, so that the width and height properties can be applied to just this Menu item?

Comment: when you reuse the `UI Bootstrap` model just give a different window class, its configurable right

Comment: I created a different window class, it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

### Customize uibModal FULLSCREEN CSS&JS CODES

**JS :**

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    animation: OrdersController.animationsEnabled,
                    ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
                    ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
                    templateUrl: 'GENERAL/Orders/orders.dialog.html',
                    controller: 'OrdersDialogController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                    size: size, //param
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: true,
                    backdropClick: false,
                    windowTopClass: '',
                    windowClass: 'my-modal', //maybe param
                    resolve: {
                        data: function () {
                            return data = { row: row, edit: type, order: vm.main, orderDetail: vm.detail };
                        }
                    }
                })
```

**CSS:**

```
.my-modal .modal-dialog {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.my-modal .modal-content {
    width: 100% !important;
    min-height: 100vh !important;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.my-modal .modal-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width:100%;
    padding:2px !important;
}
```

**REFERENCES:**

- [How do I increase modal width in Angular UI Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311736/how-do-i-increase-modal-width-in-angular-ui-bootstrap)
- [How to use custom css on uibmodal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46006605/how-to-use-custom-css-on-uibmodal-how-to-customize-the-width-and-height-of-a-ui?answertab=active#tab-top)
- [Set property Id to a uibModal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748243/set-property-id-to-a-uibmodal)

Answer (score 2):

Why not set the size through css.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**CSS:**

```
.userFileWindow .modal-content {
  width: 500px;
  height:500px;
}
.userFileWindow .modal-footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Reference:**

1. [set modal size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311736/how-do-i-increase-modal-width-in-angular-ui-bootstrap)